# Python Multiprocessing program using only 1 of the 4 cores

Tags: python

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 64-bit with processor-Intel® Core™ i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz × 4 and 16gb of RAM.
The system monitor shows 3 python processes and upon looking the resources, only 1 core is utilized to 100%, the rest 3 are just 2-3%.

As far as I know, separate processes are executed on separate cores, right?

The code being executed is:

```
import time
import multiprocessing

def boom1(*args):
    print(5**10000000000)

def boom2(*args):
    print(5**10000000000)   

def boom3(*args):
    print(5**10000000000)   

def boom4(*args):
    print(5**10000000000)

if __name__=="__main__":
    array = []
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=boom1, args=(array,))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=boom1, args=(array,))
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=boom1, args=(array,))
    p4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=boom1, args=(array,))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()


    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()

    print('Done')
```

Comment: Why do you have four `boom` functions? Why do you import `time` if it's not used?

Comment: I don't see any loops or anything so I would expect the 4 processes to make one quick print and exit immediately.

Comment: I was just comparing the difference when you call same function by 4 different processes and when you call different functions by different processes.
Was using the time module to see the difference but forgot to erase it later on.

Comment: By mistake, I asked the question in askUbuntu... my bad... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your multithreading is perfectly fine but the code which is executed is not what you expect.

Try to run this code

```
def boom1():
    print(5**10000000000)

if __name__=="__main__":
    print('Done')
```

Yes, boom1 function is not called but you'll see that 1 thread still tries to do "something" and it takes forever. Actually, this "something" is ConstantExpressionEvaluator - it tries to precompute constant expressions for performance reasons but your constant is so big that it takes all the time to finish. To break this single-threaded optimisation and run code in parallel just add this extra step to your computations.

Something like this

```
def boom1():
    z = 5 ** 10
    z = z ** 1000000000
    print(z)
```

Comment: If I call those functions like this   `p1=multiprocessing.Process(target=boom1, args=(array,))  
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=boom2, args=(array,))  
p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=boom3, args=(array,))  
p4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=boom4, args=(array,))`  
Now even before the processes are initialized, a ConstantExpressionEvaluator is run on a single core which is the reason I am not able to see the rest 3 cores being used?  
Is this what you were saying?

Comment: @Arjunsingh exactly

Comment: I executed the 2 statements in 4 functions as you specified and instantiated 4 different processes to each function and called them 
1- print(5 raised to 100)  
2= print(5 raised to 10000000)  
Now a single core is run as you said where the Constant =ExpressionEvaluator is being run to execute the command print(5 raised to 100).
But all the 4 resulted are printed instantly. What I didn't understand is if it is running on a single core then it should print them sequentially right and take some time calculating the  next print(5 raised to 100).

Comment: After it prints those 4 results, I could then see 4 Python processes being run.
Suppose if it was stored in the cache, but the I used 4 different commands in all 4 functions i.e. print(5 raised to 100), print(4 raised to 100), print(3 raised to 100), print(2 raised to 100) but then too it printed all those 4 at the same time.
Am I assuming something wrong?